# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenas tengo una base de datos en la que tengo una tabla llamada param y los campos: cod (que es mi llave única, fungiendo como id), descripción (que tiene un trabajo), read  (que tiene 0 si no se ha entregado y 1 si se entrego). quiero que al apretar un botón me modifique el campo read a 1 (que por defecto es 0), entonces estoy usando este código en el controller.

```
public function update($cod)
    {

      $cam = param::where('cod', $cod)->first();
      $cam->read = 1;
      $cam->save();
      return back()->with('mensaje', 'Trabajo completado!');

    }
```

Y en mi codigo HTML, tengo esto:

```
    @foreach($ps as $p)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            {{$p->descripcion}}             
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route("alerts.update", $p->cod) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
        <input type="submit" value="Terminado">
    </form>
   </li>
@endforeach
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto sucede este error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `param` set `read` = 1, `param`.`updated_at` = 2020-05-03 10:49:41 where `id` is null)

no se a que se puede deber, en el web.php tengo esta línea referenciada a alerts.update:

```
Route::patch('Alertas/{cod}', 'Alerts@update' )->name('alerts.update');
```

Como ven en ningún lugar hago referencia a una id o a updated_at y tampoco existen en mi tabla. Y en el modelo de param solo tengo esto:

```
class param extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'param';
}
```

Entonces no se que puede estar fallando o porque busca datos que no existen, por otra parte ya verifique si cod devuelve el valor correcto y si lo hace. Y si devuelvo cam sin  "$cam->read = 1; $cam->save();" me  devuelve la fila correcta, entonces no se a que se puede deber el error, espero puedan orientarme porque estoy confundido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `first()` va a buscar trabajar con la llave primaria asociada al modelo, que por convención debería tener el nombre de `id`.

Tu comentas que se llama `cod` entonces Eloquent no la encuentra y por tanto la consulta falla, para solucionarlo en tu modelo deberías declarar una propiedad que tenga asignado dicho valor así:

```
protected $primaryKey = "cod";
```

[Aquí puedes leer mas al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)